# Prove if $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable, then so is $|f|$ and $\left|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\right| \leq \int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that if $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable, then so is $|f|$ and $\left|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\right| \leq \int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx$

I already proved that |f| is integrable, but how do I show that $|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx| \leq \int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx$   ?

Comment: Look at the Riemann sums. ​ ​

Comment: Alternately, $-|f|\leq f\leq |f|$, then use the monotonicity of the integral.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Notice that $$-|f(x)| \leq f(x) \leq |f(x)|$$

for all $x \in [ a,b]$. and $$-\int_a^b|f(x)| dx \leq \int_a^bf(x)dx \leq \int_a^b|f(x)|dx$$

Answer (score 0):

If you have two Riemann-integrable functions $f,g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) \leq g(x) \forall x \in [a,b]$, then $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}{f(x) \mathrm dx} \leq \int_{a}^{b}{g(x) \mathrm dx}$. This follows easily from $$\inf(f([c,d])) \leq \inf(g([c,d]))\ \ \forall \text{ intervals } [c,d] \subset [a,b]$$.

Then $\displaystyle \left|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\right| \leq \int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx$ follows from $$-|f(x)|  \leq f(x) \leq |f(x)| \ \ \forall x \in [a,b]$$

Comment: oops, too slow.