# Show $|\int^{b}_{a} f(x) dx | \leq \int^{b}_{a} |f(x)| dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

Show:

$$|\int^{b}_{a} f(x) dx | \leq \int^{b}_{a}   |f(x)|$$

Hint: $-|f(x)| \leq f(x) \leq |f(x)|$ holds for all $x \in dom(f)$

I tried rewriting the integral as a riemann sum but then I just have one big absolute limit and it doesn't really help.

$$|\int^{b}_{a} f(x) dx | = |\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^{n}_{i=1}f(x_{i}^{*})\Delta x|$$

Comment: Just integrate the inequality given by the hint

Comment: You are almost there. Just note $|\int^{b}_{a} f(x) dx | = |\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^{n}_{i=1}f(x_{i}^{*})\Delta x|\le \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^{n}_{i=1}|f(x_{i}^{*})|\Delta x=\int^{b}_{a}   |f(x)|dx$

Comment: Is it included in the question that $|f|$ is integrable given that $f$ is? Otherwise one should give an argument for that.

Comment: It is integrable and continous

Comment: @User1006 how do you know that the inequality you proposed holds? How can you take absolute value of a limit and say it's less then absolute value of function

Comment: What are you treating at f(x)? The entire limit?

Comment: @K Split X, there is $|\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|$, which can be proved easily

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711885

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that $-|f (x)| \le f (x) \le |f (x)|$.

Integration conserves inequalities (if b > a) so $-\int_a^b |f (x)| \le \int_a^b f (x) \le \int_a^b |f (x)|$.

Then, by definition, this means that $|\int_a^b f (x)| \le \int_a^b |f (x)|$

Comment: How did you go from the second step to the third step?

Comment: How does $-\int^{b}_{a}|f(x)|$ turn into $|\int^{b}_{a}f(x)|$

Comment: If $-M \le a \le M $ and $M \ge 0$, then $|a| \le M $. That's maybe not the definition of absolute value, but it is straightforward. If you want to prove it, just prove it's true for every negative $a $, and that it's true for every positive $a $.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way to show it (without following the hint) would be:

Write $f$ as the sum of its positive and negative parts $$f(x)=\underbrace{\max\{f(x),0\}}_{=:f^+(x)}+\underbrace{\min\{f(x),0\}}_{=:f^-(x)},$$
and then one has, using the linearity of the integral and the triangular inequality,
\begin{align}
\left|\int_a^bf(x)\,dx\right|=&\left|\int_a^bf^+(x)\,dx+\int_a^bf^-(x)\,dx\right|\\
\leq&\left|\int_a^bf^+(x)\,dx\right|+\left|\int_a^bf^-(x)\,dx\right|\\
=&\int_a^bf^+(x)\,dx-\int_a^bf^-(x)\,dx\\
=&\int_a^b\underbrace{(f^+(x)-f^-(x))}_{=|f(x)|}\,dx.
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) This is the approach I would have suggested.  Clear and concise.